# How to work "Remember Me?" Funcitonality without using Cookie in Java?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, cookies, remember-me

First of apology to ask this Repeated Question but i have lot of confusion in that..

Actually in my spring Application Have Home.jsp, login.jsp and LoginController.java,LoginForm.
(Hear Login.jsp is include Home.jsp)
Login.jsp:

```
    <%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<fieldset id="signin_menu">
    <form:form action="login/processLogin" modelAttribute="LOGIN">
        <label for="username">Username or email</label>
        <form:input path="userName" tabindex="4" />
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="password">Password</label>
            <form:password path="password" tabindex="5" />
        </p>

        <p class="remember">
            <input id="signin_submit" value="Sign in" tabindex="6" type="submit">
            <form:checkbox path="remember" id="remember" name="remember_me"
                value="1" tabindex="7" />
            <label for="remember">RememberMe</label>
        </p>
    </form:form>
</fieldset>
```

LoginForm:

```
public class LoginForm {
private String userName;
private String password;
private boolean remember;
//Setter and getter}
```

LoginController.java

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="login")
public class LoginController {
    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;
    @Autowired
    private SessionData sessionData;

    @RequestMapping(value = "processLogin", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String processLogin(LoginForm loginForm, BindingResult result,
            Model model) {

        if (userService.authenticateUser(loginForm.getUserName(),
                loginForm.getPassword())) {
            sessionData.setUser(userService.getUser(loginForm.getUserName()));
        }
        model.addAttribute(FormType.LOGIN.name(), loginForm);
        return "redirect:/home";
    }}
```

when i'm start the server: `http://localhost:8080/EClass/home`
When Click Login Button(Login.jsp) and click`Submit` button request goes and redirect to home page,again url show: `http://localhost:8080/EClass/home`

So hear there no Cookie to get it.. How to Work Remember me? option for this situation ..

I'm really Stuck this point.. So Please help me..

Comment: did you use spring-security? this framework handles this feature for you

Comment: No.. How to use this? give some sample code.. If any Jar required for this Spring-secutity?

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear: a) does remember me works in your app and you ask why/how it works, of b) it does not work and you ask for support to get it running?

Comment: No, it is not working, give me suggestion to work with Remember Me? option with out Cookie..

Answer (score 0):

You will have to to a lot of work (mainly reading documentation and tutorials) to understand spring security and get remember me running, but it is deferentially worth to do it.

Start with the [spring security homepage](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/index.html), they have a good [getting started section](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/start-here.html).

If you have some more time and want to understand how spring security works, then I highly recommend to read the [Spring Security 3.1 book](http://www.packtpub.com/spring-security-3-1/book).

---

You asked

> How to work “Remember Me?” Funcitonality without using Cookie in Java?

The answer: Not -- It requires the cookie to identify the user/client.

---

*One other very important hint: if you look for any tutorials, documentation,... on spring security make sure that they refer to version 3.x! (Version 2.x and older "acegi" differ a lot from version 3)*

Answer (score 0):

The "remember me" feature is provided by the [spring security framewok](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/remember-me.html), which is a must if you are doing authentication & authorization in your spring-based application